# equivelent of id in radio menu html

Tags: javascript, html, variables, radio-button

I am trying to create a radio menu with three choices that I can click on.  Below is the snippet of code in which I am attempting this:

```
<html>

<form id="form" name="form">
    <tr><td align=left><input type="radio" name="grade" value="1st">1st</td></tr><br>
   <tr><td align=left><input type="radio" name="grade" value="2nd">2nd</td></tr><br>
   <tr><td align=left><input type="radio" name="grade" value="3rd">3rd</td></tr><br>
</form>
```

Now when I do other forms like input type="text" I can use id for instance:

```
<tr><td align=left><input type="text" id="grade" value="3rd">
```

When I tried using id in the radio buttons I am not able to click on just one buttons.  When I click on one button the other button remains clicked on and I cannot unclick it.  Besides I only want to user to select just one value.  With what I have been doing I have relied on id for defining variables that are stored in a template.  How can I resolve this issue using the radio buttons.  Is there anything I can do that is the equivelent of using id to define a variable?

Comment: Are you trying to pass the users input on the radio button as a variable? Radio inputs have a prop called "checked" that is a boolean which you can reference with other code.

Comment: I am trying to do that.  I want the user to select one of the values in the radio button and then that becomes a stored variable.  I have usually been able to do that using id but that does not seem to work for radio buttons.  It works for checklist and text but not radio button.  I need to know how to get around this issue.

Comment: But if you use `id` as a replacement for `name` does this mean you are using the same `id` for each element? If so then do not to do, `id`'s should be unique. The attribute `name` in radio buttons is used to group the selection. Not sure what you are trying to do by swapping `radio` for `text` though. If you want to use `text` and limit to one you can assign a `class` to those inputs and maybe use a data set `data-selected="true"` and append that to the selected `text` input.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/JSREF/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_radio_checked2 this might help. you can use the `checked` property

Answer (score 0):

Nothing prevents you to use `id` attribute on radio button groups as long as you keep name the same for all of them to build the group

```
<table>
    <tr><td align=left><input type="radio" id="grade1" name="grade" value="1st">1st</td></tr><br>
    <tr><td align=left><input type="radio" id="grade2" name="grade" value="2nd">2nd</td></tr><br>
    <tr><td align=left><input type="radio" id="grade3" name="grade" value="3rd">3rd</td></tr><br>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can still use ids like this. Also if you click a radio button, the other one will become `unchecked` since they are inside the same form.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form id="form" name="form">
        <tr><td align=left><input id="one" type="radio" name="grade" value="1st" checked>1st</td></tr><br>
       <tr><td align=left><input id="two" type="radio" name="grade" value="2nd">2nd</td></tr><br>
       <tr><td align=left><input id="three" type="radio" name="grade" value="3rd">3rd</td></tr><br>
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var onev = $('#one').val();
      console.log(onev); //logs 1st
      var twov = $('#two').val();
      console.log(twov); //logs 2nd
      var threev= $('#three').val();
      console.log(threev); //logs 3rd
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `jQuery` isn't tagged in this question. I think it would be better if you place a comment asking if the OP would be willing to use a `jQuery` solution before posting an answer.

Comment: that is just to show. doesn't harm to put a few *extra* lines to the answer @NewToJS

Comment: But to suggest loading a plugin like `jQuery` for something that can be done without having to load a library doesn't make sense. If the OP is already loading the library I'm sure `jQuery` would be tagged.

Comment: maybe you have a point :) i just put my code right in there to be quick. you can edit if you want @NewToJS

Comment: Don't get me wrong, I think having different solutions is great but I think it would be best to ask the OP if a `jQuery` solution would be an option/acceptable for them before posting one without it being tagged. That's all I wanted for you to understand :)